# Salesforce's Apex Compiler Throwing Phantom Error

Tags: apex

I have code that compiles and executes fine in execute anonymous and when combined but seems to have a weird issue otherwise:

```
private static Boolean updateWorkOrder(Id workOrderId, String responseBody) {
    if(workOrderId == null || responseBody == null || !responseBody.contains('REQ -'))

    Integer pos = responseBody.indexOf('REQ -');
    String install = responseBody.substring(pos,responseBody.length());

    WorkOrder wo = new WorkOrder(Id = workOrderId, Snap_Install__c = install);
    Database.SaveResult sr = Database.update(wo,false);
    if(sr.isSuccess()) return true;
    else return false;
    return false;
}
```

I keep getting a "Variable Does Not Exist" error. With the code below, I get pos doesn't exist on the line below it (install = ...).

If I change the line to the below, I get an error that install does not exist on the wo line.

```
String install = responseBody.substring(responseBody.indexOf('REQ -'),responseBody.length())
```

And so on... The code runs just fine when I put it in execute anonymous.

I can get the class to compile as follows:

```
if(Database.update(new WorkOrder(Id = workOrderId, Snap_Install__c = responseBody.substring(responseBody.indexOf('REQ -'),responseBody.length())),false).isSuccess()) return true;
    else return false;
    return false;
```

But this is pretty ugly. Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect the problem to be leaving out optional brackets in your first `if` statement, so the compiler expects the next line (and only the next line) to be within that block. This means the `pos` variable isn't available on the next line, which is out of the scope of the `if` block.

I'm assuming you want the method to return immediately if your `if` statement is satisfied. Give this a shot:

```
private static Boolean updateWorkOrder(Id workOrderId, String responseBody) {
    if ( workOrderId == null || responseBody == null || !responseBody.contains('REQ -') ) {
        return false;
    }

    Integer pos = responseBody.indexOf('REQ -');
    String install = responseBody.substring(pos,responseBody.length());
    WorkOrder wo = new WorkOrder(Id = workOrderId, Snap_Install__c = install);
    Database.SaveResult sr = Database.update(wo,false);
    return sr.isSuccess();
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`pos` has a (block) scope of the first `if` statement, it's created and destroyed within the block. Without explicit declaration of the block via curly braces, only the first instruction that follows the `if` statement belongs to the block. Your code

```
if(workOrderId == null || responseBody == null || !responseBody.contains('REQ -'))

    Integer pos = responseBody.indexOf('REQ -');
    String install = responseBody.substring(pos,responseBody.length());
```

is equivalent to

```
if(workOrderId == null || responseBody == null || !responseBody.contains('REQ -')) {
    Integer pos = responseBody.indexOf('REQ -');
}

String install = responseBody.substring(pos,responseBody.length());
```

When you attempt to use `pos` in `responseBody.substring(...)`, the compiler correctly complains because `pos` does not exist at this point. This is why using braces to denote blocks is the best practice - it helps avoid issues like this one and it improves maintainability by making the code more readable.